# Can't Use clj-http On Windows Clojure Project

Tags: java, clojure, leiningen

I'm 100% new to clojure/lein.

The project.clj looks like so

```
    (defproject pio-cache "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
     :description "FIXME: write description"
     :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
     :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
     :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
                 [clj-http "0.9.2"]]
     :main pio-cache.core/main

     )
```

And my core file looks like

```
(ns pio-cache.core
   (:require [clj-http.client :as client])
)
```

But i can't use clj-http. When i try to run it i keep getting:

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate clj_http/client__init.class or clj_http/client.clj on classpath`

I've tried running `lein deps` and `lein classpath`. Nothing fixes it.

#### Edit - Adding lein deps :tree

```
    [clj-http "0.9.2"]
       [cheshire "5.3.1" :exclusions [[org.clojure/clojure]]]
         [com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core "2.3.1"]
         [com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-smile "2.3.1"]
         [tigris "0.1.1"]
       [commons-codec "1.9" :exclusions [[org.clojure/clojure]]]
       [commons-io "2.4" :exclusions [[org.clojure/clojure]]]
       [crouton "0.1.2" :exclusions [[org.clojure/clojure]]]
         [org.jsoup/jsoup "1.7.1"]
       [org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient "4.3.3" :exclusions [[org.clojure/clojure]]]
         [commons-logging "1.1.3"]
       [org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore "4.3.2" :exclusions [[org.clojure/clojure]]]
       [org.apache.httpcomponents/httpmime "4.3.3" :exclusions [[org.clojure/clojure]]]
       [org.clojure/tools.reader "0.8.4" :exclusions [[org.clojure/clojure]]]
       [potemkin "0.3.4" :exclusions [[org.clojure/clojure]]]
         [clj-tuple "0.1.2"]
         [riddley "0.1.6"]
       [slingshot "0.10.3" :exclusions [[org.clojure/clojure]]]
     [clojure-complete "0.2.3" :exclusions [[org.clojure/clojure]]]
     [org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]
     [org.clojure/tools.nrepl "0.2.3" :exclusions [[org.clojure/clojure]]]
```

Comment: I can't reproduce any issue -- after getting rid of the reference to pio-cache.core/main (since you aren't actually providing one), seems perfectly fine here.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy how are classpath issues like this normally fixed?

Comment: Well -- I'd start by running (and adding to your question the output from) `lein deps-tree`. This will also give us some hints about your environment (for instance, if you're loading any leiningen plugins conflicting with the desired dependency chain).

Comment: ...*normally*, when there's a library problem, it's because something else is conflicting with what you're asking for -- resulting in a newer version being used than what you wanted, or a library that has conflicting classes added by mistake, or whatnot. Your dependency chain is so simple here as to make that unlikely, which is why this question is... unusual. Unless you have big hairy lein plugins in use. :)

Comment: ...and, yeah, that's pretty straightforward. You're getting a newer Clojure runtime than the one you asked for, but that shouldn't generally hurt things.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy i literally just downloaded lein and thought i'd try to learn some clojure via making web requests and having fun with them

Comment: Quick question -- when you say "try to run it", how do you get to the repl where you're doing that? Or is this "lein run", or something else?

Comment: `lein run` and `ctrl-enter` in lighttable at the end of the form

Comment: If you look through the output of `lein classpath`, you should see the path to the clj-http jar. As a sanity check, you might poke at it to ensure that it's correct and complete (though an issue where it weren't would be... very unusual).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went into another directory, had `lein` generate a ring-based app template and download its dependencies, then came back into this project's directory and suddenly the dependency download just started working.... ?